# ¿Como usar list(map()) en python?

Tags: python, map, parsear

Tengo una lista que contiene a su vez varias listas. Todas estas contienen unica y exclusivamente str equivalente a numeros: '1','10',etc. Lo que quiero es recorrer todas las listas de mi lista principal y parsear esos strings a float.

```
x0 = ['3', '8', '4', '2', '3', '7', '8', '4', '2', '3']
x1 = ['4', '9', '5', '3', '10', '4', '9', '5', '3', '1']
x2 =['5', '10', '6', '4', '11', '11', '10', '6', '4', '9']
lista_de_listas = [x0,x1,x2]
```

Quiero utilizar el método map() y he intentado lo siguiente:

```
for i in lista_de_listas:
    res = list(map(float,i))
    i = res
```

Pero no hace nada si lo intento hacer de esa manera. He pensado que si no intento asignarselo a i en el mismo ciclo quizas funcionase y se me ha ocurrido:

```
for i in lista_de_listas:
    res = list(map(float,i))
    lista_de_listas.append(res)
    lista_de_listas.remove(i)
```

Pero se me queda uno sin parsear:

```
[['4', '9', '5', '3', '10', '4', '9', '5', '3', '1'], [3.0, 8.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 7.0, 8.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0], [5.0, 10.0, 6.0, 4.0, 11.0, 11.0, 10.0, 6.0, 4.0, 9.0]]
```

Se que el método map() sirve exactamente para lo que estoy tratando de hacer pero por mucho que pruebe no doy con la tecla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé que sea la forma del resultado que buscas, pero quizás estás buscando:

```py
resulta = [list(map(float, lista)) for lista in lista_de_listas]
```

O bien podrías eliminar `lista_de_listas`, si no necesitas por otro motivo, creándolo en directo:

```py
lista_de_listas = [list(map(float, lista) for lista in [x0, x1, x2]]
```

En ambos casos, la nueva lista externa está creado por aplicar `map(float)` a cada una de `x0`, `x1`, `x2`.